# Helm would not show line previews if used regexp

Tags: helm, regular-expressions

When I use regular expressions in *helm occur* for narrowing, it does not show line previews

[image]

Is this normal functioning? If so, are there any workarounds?

**Update:**

I found out that the error only occurs when I use white characters in a set.

Comment: Most likely a bug, getting the same for `M-x helm-do-grep` and a pattern including `\(` (which is pretty useful when searching Lisp code).  Please open a ticket.

Comment: Thank you @wasamasa I wrote an issue to Helm's github. I assume this is the same thing like open a ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to thierryvolpiatto from Helm's github, I learnt the answer. Helm interprets spaces as search pattern separators so they should be escaped with backslashes.